# How to merge changes from another branch into your branch in WebStorm

Tags: git, webstorm

Is there a way to merge from a remote branch into my branch in Webstorm, using tools provided by the IDE. I am able to do in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

- First fetch your remote branch
- select current branch as other branch you want to merge
- from git toolbar select **merge into current**

find more in documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/manage-branches.html)

Comment: Thank you! I have my branch checked out   How do I fetch the remote branch? Is this the same as doing an Update Project?

Comment: You can click on remote branch that you want to fetch in git toolbox and click on checkout.